# How to encode an object to json in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the object "Week" to json.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json this is the source that i used

```
class Week{
  DateTime _startDate;
  DateTime _endDate;
  List<Goal> _goalList;
  String _improvement;

  Week(this._startDate, this._endDate){
    this._goalList = List<Goal>();
    this._improvement = "";
  }

  Week.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : _startDate =  json['startDate'],
      _endDate = json['endDate'],
      _goalList = json['goalList'],
      _improvement = json['improvement'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => 
  {
    'startDate': _startDate,
    'endDate': _endDate,
    'goalList': _goalList,
    'improvement': _improvement,
  };
}
```

I used this:

```
DateTime startDate = currentDate.subtract(new Duration(days:(weekday-1)));
DateTime endDate = currentDate.add(new Duration(days:(7-weekday)));

Week week = new Week(startDate, endDate);
var json = jsonEncode(week);
```

But the problem is that I get this result:

```
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Week'
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:647:7)
#1      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:834:17)
#2      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:819:5)
#3      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:255:30)
#4      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:166:45)
#5      jsonEncode (dart:convert/json.dart:80:10)
```

Comment: FWIW, I find the naming of the methods "toJson" somewhat inappropriate as they are really "toMapStringDynamic" methods. It's the jsonEncode function that actually does the "toJson-ing".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

jsonEncode requires a `Map<String, dynamic>`, not a `Week` object. Calling your `toJson()` method should do the trick.

```
var json = jsonEncode(week.toJson());
```

However, keep in mind that your `toJson()` method is also incorrect, as things like _goalList and the dates are still objects, not Maps or Lists. You'll need to implement toJson methods on those as well.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Because dart is not javascript / typescript. Dart checks types at runtime, therefore you have to explicitly tell it how to convert things - also there is no reflection in dart, so it can't figure it out by itself.
2. You can use a library that uses code generation to do these things automatically for you - it still wont be possible at runtime though - read more about [JSON serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#use-code-generation-for-medium-to-large-projects).
3. The easiest way would be to implement the methods directly in the classes, as that's where you have access to in your root object. Keep in mind that the structure that `jsonEncode` needs is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, but the `dynamic` part really means `List<dynamic>`, `Map<String, dynamic>` or a primitive that is json compatible such as `String` or `double` - if you try to imagine how such a nested structure of said types looks, you'll realise that it's basically json. So when you do something like `'goalList': _goalList,` you're giving it an object, which is not one of the allowed types.

Hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: thank you for your fast response. I have a few questions now: 1. Why is the converting of objects to json that complicated? 2. Is there no easier way? and 3. How can I implement those `toJson()` methods? Do I have to make separate classes or can I implement them into the `Week` class?

Comment: what about object inside an object ??

Comment: Seems like a TON of boilerplate work needed in flutter/dart for routine serialization of the data fields in a complex nested object. Surely there's a better way?! Pining for  language supported magic to go from object to map and back again (like you find in things like PHP) .

Answer (score 24):

for anyone wondering: I got my solution.

To make my code work I needed to implement the `toJson()` methods at my class `Goal` as well (because I used `List<Goal>` in `Week`).

```
class Goal{
  String _text;
  bool _reached;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'text': _text,
    'reached': _reached,
  }; 
}
```

Also, I needed to add `.toIso8601String()` to the `DateTime` objects like that in the `Week` class:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => 
  {
    'startDate': _startDate.toIso8601String(),
    'endDate': _endDate.toIso8601String(),
    'goalList': _goalList,
    'improvement': _improvement,
  };
```

Now the output is:

```
 {"startDate":"2019-05-27T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2019-06-02T00:00:00.000Z","goalList":[],"improvement":""}
```

Comment: Big shoutout to @Philip who explained this so well!

Comment: I have a question. The way you wrote the constructor for week 

Week(this._startDate, this._endDate){
    this._goalList = List<Goal>();
    this._improvement = "";
  }

How do you instantiate a class like this?

Comment: I mean how did you assign values to _goalList & _improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Taking suggestion 2 from @Phillip's answer above for Json serialization, the Freezed package I believe you can skip the `@JsonSerializable` annotation and just used the `@Freezed` annotation because Freezed "will automatically ask json_serializable to generate all the necessary fromJson/toJson."
So the example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#use-code-generation-for-medium-to-large-projects
becomes:

```
//import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

/// This allows the `User` class to access private members in
/// the generated file. The value for this is *.g.dart, where
/// the star denotes the source file name.
part 'user.g.dart';
part 'user.freezed.dart';
/// An annotation for the code generator to know that this class needs the
/// JSON serialization logic to be generated.
@freezed
class User {
  User(this.name, this.email);

  String name;
  String email;

  /// A necessary factory constructor for creating a new User instance
  /// from a map. Pass the map to the generated `_$UserFromJson()` constructor.
  /// The constructor is named after the source class, in this case, User.
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  /// `toJson` is the convention for a class to declare support for serialization
  /// to JSON. The implementation simply calls the private, generated
  /// helper method `_$UserToJson`.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

Freezed: https://pub.dev/packages/freezed
Don't forget to edit `pubspec.yaml` for `freezed` and `freezed_annotation`