# Flutter FCM: send documentSnapshot in data message

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am pretty new to programming, so I count on your kindness.
Is it possible to send other types than Strings in FCM data message payload, like bool, List or even a documentSnapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [reference documentation for `message.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message.FIELDS.data) it is defined as:

> data
>
> map (key: string, value: string)
>
> Input only. Arbitrary key/value payload. The key should not be a reserved word (`"from"`, `"message_type"`, or any word starting with `"google"` or `"gcm"`).
>
> An object containing a list of `"key": value` pairs. Example: `{ "name": "wrench", "mass": "1.3kg", "count": "3" }`.

So it is a flat list of key value pairs, where both key and value are strings. If course you can store any data you want in that value, as long as you encode/decode it as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to decode this JSON and then cast it (the string value) to another type?

Comment: It's just a string, so your question becomes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406601/how-to-encode-an-object-to-json-in-flutter